# nave not switchning node version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nave

I am new to nave, and maybe I don't understand something, but should nave actually change the node version?

Example:

The node version I got installed on my computer is `7.2.0`.

When I do "`nave ls`", I get the following installed versions:

```
5.12.0  6.9.2   7.3.0
```

Then, I do "nave use 5.12.0" and then "`node --version`". It still says `7.2.0`.

Does it look like I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: what's your `$PATH` look like?

Comment: Here it is: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/bin:~/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/hristod/bin:/Users/hristod/.composer/vendor/bin

This is when I'm in the subshell, if it's of any importance...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my path to start with "$PATH:.........." in my .zshrc. I had a hard coded path before, that's why nave wasn't able to change it in the subshell!